# SQL error : Too few parameter while inserting sql query to Ireport

Tags: sql, ms-access

this is my sql query which used to insert into ireport..

```
SELECT Format([DatePaid],"mmmm") AS Expr1
    , Sum(Payment.[TotalAmount]) AS TotalAmountOfCount
FROM Payment
GROUP BY Format([DatePaid],"mmmm");
```

Here's the problem..

> SQL problems : [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few
>   parameters. Expected 1.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste the query into the query design window. It will highlight the problem. It is likely that a field name has been misspelled.